# How to pass customized arguments in an eventhander within a hander

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagrid

I was trying to make a contextMenu from The datagridview class, if the user clicks the option on the menu, it will pop-up an input window and change datagridview based on the input, but I'm not sure how to pass argument in a nested hander.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewCell clickedCell = (sender as DataGridView).Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
    ContextMenuStrip menu = new ContextMenuStrip();
    menu.Items.Add("Edit").Name = "edit";
    menu.Show(Cursor.Position);
    menu.ItemClicked += new ToolStripItemClickedEventHandler(menu_ItemClicked);
}

    private void menu_ItemClicked(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.ClickedItem.Name.ToString())
        {
            case "edit":
                string promptValue = Prompt.ShowDialog("input:", "input");
                // clickedCell.Value = ...
                // How do  I access clickedCell from the calling handler?
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

    }
```

How do I access clickedCell from the calling handler?

Comment: You could instead put the clickedCell  into the dataGridView1.Tag. Also: Do you add the menu item nultiple times? Ditto for its event hanfler?

Comment: @TaW Yeah I figured out that I just need to add a private member